# Side by side inputs in form - HTML, Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am using Flask to develop a web application. I want to put a form in the main page that allows the user to upload a file and submit to the server.

This is working:

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Automatic Guitar Music Transcription</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="lead">Upload your audio file below:</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="file" type="file"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/))

However, my real `index.html` is a Flask template, and also uses Bootstrap.

```
{%- extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}

{% block content %}
  {% if request == "GET": %}

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Automatic Guitar Music Transcription</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="lead">Upload your audio file below:</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="file" type="file"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>

  ...more HTML...

  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/master/dist/recorder.js"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/record.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, this way, I don't get the input buttons side by side like in the JSFiddle, but I get the submit button under the file upload button:

[image: buttons]

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple table to achieve this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="file" type="file"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```